# Create a LTR Activity in an RTL-Supported Android App

Tags: android, locale, toolbar, right-to-left

I've set my application to support RTL by adding the "supportRTL = true" to the Android Manifest. Now I Want to create an activity with a LTR orientation, meaning the Toolbar should appear LTR and not RTL. Problem is, whatever I do, I can't get the toolbar to switch back to LTR. How should I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want just one Activity to be LTR?

Comment: I want to be able to change app locale regardless of the phone's locale. Default language is Hebrew, and I need to be able to switch to English.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> android:layoutDirection="ltr"

only used in API level 17 and higher